# Does studying multiples subjects in parallel effect performance?

Tags: learning, memory, reference-request

[Researches](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-xiaomi&ei=1UGsXOznNcOPr7wP-NmOkAg&q=multitasking%20is%20bad%20stanford&oq=multitasking%20is%20bad%20stanford&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..33i21.5403.7641..7870...0.0..0.431.2119.2-7j0j1......0....1.........0i71j0j0i22i30j33i22i29i30j33i160j33i13i21.MhIt4DiTiOw) shown that multitasking is really bad.

But, does studying multiple subjects in parallel comes under it?

Is it okay to switch between the subjects (mathematics, physics, biology, ....) In small amounts of time (say 15-30 minutes)?  Is there any research on it whether is efficient or not for comprehending and deep understanding of subjects?

`My personal experience`: I tried to study 4 subjects in parallel for every 15-30 minutes (based on interest on the subject or boredom on the subject )for each subject, I notice an increase in my studying time and the breadth, as well as the depth of topics and I, 'm not getting any boredom and constantly thinking about subjects. So, feeling better than studying only a single subject for more time (say 3 hours).

Comment: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/11034/is-it-better-to-study-multiple-subjects-simultaneously-or-focus-on-one-subject-i might be the same question. But I find the answers there (including the accepted one) making too many logical jumps from short-term task switching to what was really the topic of the question.

Comment: In [particular](https://doi.org/10.1080/1358165042000283101) "Observational analyses revealed significant relationships between
learning and the affective states of boredom, flow and confusion."

Comment: Studying one subject for 15 minutes, then another for 15 minutes, etc, sounds like studying in *series*, not in parallel.